# How to concatenate files with a new line between files in dos command line

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, copy

I know I can concatenate files in a directory like:

```
copy /b *.txt all.txt
```

But I got one more question. How should I put new line between each files? I found that it's a problem for copy /b command. Think about this situation:

```
content of a.txt: --ALTER TABLE table1 ...;
content of b.txt: CREATE TABLE table2 ...;
content of c.txt: DROP TABLE table3 ...;
```

I hope the result of the concatenation will be

```
--ALTER TABLE table1 ...;
CREATE TABLE table2 ...;
DROP TABLE table3 ...;
```

instead of

```
--ALTER TABLE table1 ...;CREATE TABLE table2 ...;DROP TABLE table3 ...;
```

, in which the content could be regarded as a comment.

Comment: There are a couple of approaches.  1) append a CRLF to the end of each file.  This depends on the files being in a format that each file needs one.  2) actually checking if there is a crlf at the end of each file and appending one if it doesn't have one.  3) parsing the files and rewriting them so each file has a crlf at the end.

Comment: it seems that no one command could fix this problem alone.

Answer (score 6):

```
(for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d *.txt') do (
    type "%%~a"
    echo(
  )
)>all.txt
```

Comment: That's 1) in my comment and it'll work well - but lines that end in a blank line will then have two blank lines.

Comment: Try it now.  There was a parenthesis missing.

Comment: @barto 'echo(' needs no closing parenthesis.